# Override js in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2

How to override

> Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js

Answer (score 1):

You can override it into your module or theme.

**How Into your theme :**

create requirejs-config.js file into your theme root folder and add following code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {            
            "Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method": "js/override/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method"
        }
    }
};
```

then create following path folders into your theme from root:

```
web/js/override/view/payment/method-renderer
```

and add that js file into this created folder.

**OR**

**How Into your module**

create requirejs-config.js file into Your Module :

[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

and add this :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method'
        }
    }
};
```

Also don't forget to run deploy command after override file
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush

Thanks

Comment: I need to add custom function in that file ....so can i use map or mixins

Comment: i think you should use map, because a mixin is a class whose methods are added to, or mixed in, with another class. This allows you to return a new instance of the target component with your modifications attached to it before it is used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

To override `Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js` in your theme, just copy the file and place under theme in the same path as above and run the following command after that:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

This will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Mixin** instead of **Map**.

In your **require-js** add below code.

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
 config: {
     mixins: {
         'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/cashondelivery-method': {
             'Namespace_Modeulename/js/cashondelivery-method': true
         }
     }
 }
};
```

> Namespace/Modeulename/view/frontend/web/js/cashondelivery-method

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, url) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.cashondelivery', widget, {

        });
        return $.mage.cashondelivery;
    }
});
```

I hope it helps!